# C++ Boost Mutex Lock

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

Recently I am playing around Boost mutex and I am not sure if I can do the following:

```
boost::recursive_mutex ListLock;

int main(){
  ListLock.lock();
  function1();
  ListLock.unlock();
}

void function1(){
  ListLock.lock();
  //some operations
  ListLock.unlock();
}
```

Is it okay to lock the ListLock twice?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What happens when you try to compile this; or run it later? What is your question?

Comment: Sure you can do it, although it won't compile. However, none of the problems have anything to do with you locking recursively, which is what I have a feeling you're trying to ask.

Comment: That's the whole idea of `recursive_mutex`. You can lock it recursively (although please consider using a `unique_lock` or a `lock_guard` to avoid locking the mutex manually).

Comment: You will get a runtime error.  You must use `boost::recursive_mutex` if your program needs mutex lock reentrance.   Make sure you use `boost::lock_guard'  It will save you a lot of grief.  Promise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the lock. Recursive locks allow ... recursive locks. So, no problem in your example.

Non-recursive locks (such as std::mutex or boost::mutex) would deadlock (technically, I think the behaviour is unspecified, but most POSIX thread implementations either deadlock or raise an exception based on EDEADLK).

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex for `recursive_mutex`